# Getting text outside of a tag in selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, dom

I am trying to get the text that is located outside of this label and inside the div

```
<div style="color:red;">
<label> Total Amount Due:</label>
$0.00
</div>
```

Here all I am trying to extract is the $0.00

I have tried using the xpath of the div to get the number but it still includes the text of the label saying Total Amount Due: $0.00

```
amount_finder  =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/font[1]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[10]")
for amount in amount_finder:
    print(amount.text)
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to just get the $0.00. I am new to to this and having trouble search previous posts on here and applying it to my situation. I see various recommendations of using following-sibling but can't get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are looping through all the elements in `amount_finder`

You just need to get the text from the div element itself.

```
amount = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/font[1]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[10]').text()
print(amount)
```

You can also use simply use Xpath or Query Selector instead of Full Xpath.

Use `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`, if you are running this code. Using `By` is much easier compared to old `find_elements_by_xpath`

Comment: `find_elements` returns a `List`. So you cannot use `.text()` method

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, @Shawn. My bad, I meant `find_element`

Answer (score 0):

You can use text() node of XPath:

```
//div/text()[2]
```

but, since it is not an element but a text node, selenium cannot process it. So the solution is to run XPath by Javascript:

```
node_text = driver.execute_script("return document.evaluate('//div//text()[2]', document).iterateNext().textContent;")
```